# I added a foreign key to an existing database and when I tried to publish it this error came up

Tags: sql

An error occurred while the batch was being processed

[image: Error]

Comment: Look at the various output windows to find what the actual error is.

Comment: Please describe properly

Comment: Which dbms is this? (More of a product issue than a SQL language issue...)

Comment: Thanks , solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Foreign key should always follow **referential integrity constraint**. Referential integrity constraint states that whenever adding value to foreign key column in child table, it should have equivalent primary key value in parent table.

Here in your case, as you said, you added a foreign key to an existing database table, so it may be possible that values in that table are violating referential integrity constraint, which is producing error.